# AOSP: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: command not found even though it is present in prebuilts folder

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, android-source

I am trying to compile AOSP android m,

I am getting error:

> /bin/sh: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: command not found

But it is available at:

> ./prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   ./prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/cit-arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   ./prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   v=

Please help understand in case path variable is getting set somewhere in build process or I need to add that in system path variable.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly invoke it by the full path, ie ./prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc or whatever is appropriate?  Is it marked executable?

Comment: It does detect command and gives error saying no input file i specified.
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: That's a good sign - that is what gcc does if you invoke it without anything useful to do.  So it seems that your earlier problem was not having it in your path or not invoking it by location.

Comment: thanks Chris, Can you help understand if AOSP creates custom path variables while build process which tells where the necessary tool chains are? also ubuntu's apt-get has package for  arm-linux-androideabi-gcc, will that be helpful for this or that is different?

Answer (score 0):

(I want to comment, but I don't have enough credits yet)

Is it compatible with your system? 
I have had problems when using non x86-64 compilers on a x86-64 system.

I don't remember how I meditated this but i think it was like this:
http://ccm.net/faq/1137-compiling-testing-in-32-bit-on-ubuntu-x86-64